# ASP.NET Menu force single line and not wrap

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I've scanned the Internet and oddly, no solutions have worked so far.

I have the below menu:

Site.Master ASP.NET:

```
<div class="menuBackground">
    <div id="MenuDiv" style="visibility: hidden">
        <asp:Menu ID="SiteMenu" CssClass="menu" IncludeStyleBlock="false" runat="server"
            DataSourceID="NedTreasurySiteMapDataSource" Orientation="Horizontal" OnMenuItemDataBound="SiteMenu_MenuItemDataBound"
            ClientIDMode="Static">
            <StaticItemTemplate>
                <div>
                    <%# Eval("Text") %>
                </div>
            </StaticItemTemplate>
            <DynamicItemTemplate>
                <div>
                    <%# Eval("Text") %></div>
            </DynamicItemTemplate>
        </asp:Menu>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
div.menu
{

}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 1000;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 1000;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1000;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

The issue:
When the browser is resized to a much smaller size, the menu wraps, when I want it not to. 
I want it to behave as if the contents were cropped, like an `overflow: hidden;`, remain in a single line, like `display: inline` and act as a block, retaining the current look.

Good:
[image: full size, looks ok]

Bad:
[image: small browser, looks bad]

I was pretty sure that changing the `display: block;` to `display: inline-block;` would work, but did not. Using `display: inline;` puts them in a single line, but messes up their size, since it no longer behaves as a block.

Also, I've tried adding

```
div.menu ul li
{
    display: inline-block !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

Which also did not do the trick.

Any ideas guys and girl?
TIA.

Comment: can you not place a fixed width on menudiv try using min-width

Comment: give a fixed with to wrapper of ur website or menu ul.

Comment: that seems to be doing the trick when i use the actual px, but now the whole menu is got the height permanently longer... i'm getting there. thanks!

Comment: @NicholasKing alright, the width in px fixed it, with some minor cosmetics here and there. please post it as an answer so i can mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place a fixed width on the menudiv it should solve your issues.

Thanks

Nicholas

Answer (score 0):

Fix the width on `menudiv`, try that.